# Separate number/letter tokens in Python

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm using `re.split()` to separate a string into tokens. Currently the pattern I'm using as the argument is `[^\dA-Za-z]`, which retrieves alphanumeric tokens from the string.

However, what I need is to also split tokens that have both numbers and letters into tokens with only one or the other, eg.

```
re.split(pattern, "my t0kens")
```

would return `["my", "t", "0", "kens"]`.

I'm guessing I might need to use lookahead/lookbehind, but I'm not sure if that's actually necessary or if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the findall method instead.

```
>>> print re.findall ('[^\d ]+', "my t0kens");
['my', 't', 'kens']
>>> print re.findall ('[\d]+', "my t0kens");
['0']
>>>
```

Edit: Better way from Bart's comment below.

```
>>> print re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+|\\d+', "my t0kens")
['my', 't', '0', 'kens']
>>>
```

Comment: you could squeeze in the combination of your two suggestions: `print re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+|\\d+', "my t0kens")`, which returns: `['my', 't', '0', 'kens']`

Comment: @Bart - yes that is much better !

Comment: With Bart's edit, this is definitely better than my answer. +1

Comment: also, using raw strings for regex is advisable. No need to escape those slashes. e.g. `r'[a-zA-Z]+|\d+'`

Comment: Thanks to @kjp and @Bart - the edited version does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [x for x in re.split(r'\s+|(\d+)',"my t0kens") if x]
['my', 't', '0', 'kens']
```

By using capturing parenthesis within the pattern, the tokens will also be return. Since you only want to maintain digits and not the spaces, I've left the `\s` outside the parenthesis so `None` is returned which can then be filtered out using a simple loop.

Comment: This works if there are only single digits to be retrieved - in the general case there may multiple, sorry if my example misled you.

Comment: That's easily fixed. Answer updated. Of course, the solution in kjp's answer is still more elegant. Use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Should be one line of code

```
re.findall('[a-z]+|[\d]+', 'my t0kens')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but removing space from the list below is easy :-)

```
re.split('([\d ])', 'my t0kens')
['my', ' ', 't', '0', 'kens']
```

[docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split): "Split string by the occurrences of pattern. If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list."